# R - convert chr value to num from multiple columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, char, numbers

I have this data frame and I want to change the chr values to num:

```
> dput(Df)
structure(list(`@MeasurementDateGMT` = c("2016-09-01 00:00:00", 
"2016-09-01 01:00:00", "2016-09-01 02:00:00", "2016-09-01 03:00:00", 
"2016-09-01 04:00:00", "2016-09-01 05:00:00", "2016-09-01 06:00:00", 
"2016-09-01 07:00:00", "2016-09-01 08:00:00", "2016-09-01 09:00:00", 
"2016-09-01 10:00:00", "2016-09-01 11:00:00", "2016-09-01 12:00:00", 
"2016-09-01 13:00:00", "2016-09-01 14:00:00", "2016-09-01 15:00:00", 
"2016-09-01 16:00:00", "2016-09-01 17:00:00", "2016-09-01 18:00:00", 
"2016-09-01 19:00:00", "2016-09-01 20:00:00", "2016-09-01 21:00:00", 
"2016-09-01 22:00:00", "2016-09-01 23:00:00"), `@Value` = c("10.9", 
"9.8", "9.9", "14.1", "13.6", "16.5", "15", "18.5", "18", "17", 
"16.6", "12", "12.1", "18.1", "15.9", "15.9", "16.9", "21.6", 
"23.5", "40.7", "16.6", "12.7", "12.4", "12.2")), .Names = c("@MeasurementDateGMT", 
"@Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 24L))
```

Code to convert:

```
columns <- sapply(Df, is.factor)
Df[, columns] <- lapply(Df[, columns, drop = FALSE], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Result:

```
> str(Df)
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ @MeasurementDateGMT: chr  "2016-09-01 00:00:00" "2016-09-01 01:00:00" "2016-09-01 02:00:00" "2016-09-01 03:00:00" ...
 $ @Value             : chr  "10.9" "9.8" "9.9" "14.1" ...
```

They are still `chr`. What have I missed? any ideas?

Comment: `columns` returns `c(FALSE,FALSE)`. You're `lapply`-ing a function to nothing. See `Df[, columns]`

Comment: @ikop - exactly, OP's code works fine. The `as.numeric(as.character(...` is in fact good practice for converting a factor variable. It's just a pity there aren't any factors in `Df` to start with. :-/

Comment: @thelatemail what result should `columns` return?

Comment: Presumably something that actually selects columns if you want your `Df[, columns] <- lapply(...)` to have any effect. Instead of all `FALSE`, you would need at least one `TRUE`. You don't get that, because you assign `columns` on the basis of `is.factor`, and your `Df` doesn't have any `factor`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `type.convert`.

```
Df[] <- lapply(Df, function(x) type.convert(x, as.is = TRUE))
str(Df)
#'data.frame':   24 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ @MeasurementDateGMT: chr  "2016-09-01 00:00:00" "2016-09-01 01:00:00" "2016-09-01 02:00:00" "2016-09-01 03:00:00" ...
#$ @Value             : num  10.9 9.8 9.9 14.1 13.6 16.5 15 18.5 18 17
```

...

If we need to convert the 'datetime' column,

```
Df[[2]] <- as.POSIXct(Df[[2]])
```

As the columns are all `character` in the OP's post, we don't need to convert it to `characcter` before applying `type.convert` otherwise use `type.convert(as.character(x), ..`

---

Okay, if we need `dplyr` to do this

```
library(dplyr)
res <- Df %>% 
         mutate_all(funs(type.convert(as.character(.), as.is = TRUE)))
str(res)
#'data.frame':   24 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ @MeasurementDateGMT: chr  "2016-09-01 00:00:00" "2016-09-01 01:00:00" "2016-09-01 02:00:00" "2016-09-01 03:00:00" ...
#$ @Value             : num  10.9 9.8 9.9 14.1 13.6 16.5 15 18.5 18 17 ...
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) type.convert(x, as.is = TRUE))]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but the date is `chr`. how can i change it to `POSIXct, format`?

Comment: @teelou Your title is to convert 'chr' to 'numeric'  column.  So, I thought you can convert the 'datetime' column later

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::mutate_if` which applies a function (in this case `as.numeric`) to all columns that satisfy a predicate function (in this case `is.character`).

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% # removes the "@" from names since that messes up mutate_if
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% # just for the nice printing
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)

#> Warning in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos): NAs introduced by
#> coercion

#> # A tibble: 24 x 2
#>    x_measurementdategmt x_value
#>                   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1                   NA    10.9
#>  2                   NA     9.8
#>  3                   NA     9.9
#>  4                   NA    14.1
#>  5                   NA    13.6
#>  6                   NA    16.5
#>  7                   NA    15.0
#>  8                   NA    18.5
#>  9                   NA    18.0
#> 10                   NA    17.0
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

But the above doesn't work well for the first column since it is a datetime. It just gets set to *`NA`* by `as.numeric` because it includes non-numeric characters. Instead you probably should change it to a datetime variable.

```r
df %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(x_measurementdategmt = lubridate::as_datetime(x_measurementdategmt)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)
#> # A tibble: 24 x 2
#>    x_measurementdategmt x_value
#>                  <dttm>   <dbl>
#>  1  2016-09-01 04:00:00    10.9
#>  2  2016-09-01 05:00:00     9.8
#>  3  2016-09-01 06:00:00     9.9
#>  4  2016-09-01 07:00:00    14.1
#>  5  2016-09-01 08:00:00    13.6
#>  6  2016-09-01 09:00:00    16.5
#>  7  2016-09-01 10:00:00    15.0
#>  8  2016-09-01 11:00:00    18.5
#>  9  2016-09-01 12:00:00    18.0
#> 10  2016-09-01 13:00:00    17.0
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```